# vue js - check one radio button by default

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In each set of group I wants to select one radio input by default.

[image]

each menu have multiple items. user need to select one item from each menu. so, I'm trying to select one item by default. How can I do that?

```
<div v-for="menu in menus">
    <h4>@{{ menu.name }}</h4>
    <div v-for="item in menu.menuitems">
        <input type="radio" v-model="selected_items[menu.id]" :value="item" :key="item.item_id"> @{{ item.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to group radiobuttons by menu.name add the name attribute to an input element like this:
```
  <input type="radio" name="menu.name" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, you need to set a `name` attribute to the radio buttons in each menu, so that only one can be selected at a time.
2. And to set the first item of each menu as selected, you can use `v-for` index like:

   ```
   <div v-for="item in menu.menuitems">
       <input type="radio" v-model="selected_items[menu.id]" 
           :value="item.id" 
           :name="menu.id"
           :key="item.item_id"> @{{ item.name }}
   </div>
   ```

You will also need to update radio button `:value` from `items` to `item.item_id` and also modify `:key="items.item_id"` to `:key="item.item_id"`. I think this was typo, as no variable exists in this scope like `items`.

and then inside `mounted` vue instance or any initial function inside `methods` you can set the values for each group item like:

```
mounted: function() {
   this.menus.forEach(function(menu) {
      this.selected_items[menu.id] = this.menu.menuitems.length ? this.menu.menuitems[0].id : null;
   })
}
```

assuming `menuitems[0]` in an object with properties like `item_id` & `name`

You can still get selected item for each menu like:

```
this.menus.forEach(function(menu) {
    var selectedItem = this.menu.menuitems.find(m => m.id == this.selected_items[menu.id]);
   console.log(selectedItem)
   // Retursn { id: xxx, name: 'xxx' }
})
```

Comment: You can try the updated code once. Please also fix the typos you have in the radio button bindings.

Comment: when I change :value from item to item.id , it is working. reason for keep :value="item" , I want to get name and id for save purpose

Comment: I wants to pass selected items name and id to next screen

Comment: You can still get id & name using the updated code by using only `:value="item.id"`

Comment: you removed :checked="index == 0"?

Comment: That is not needed anymore, as the checked status is auto set when we update the model `selected_items[menu.id]` value on load.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your support